# Equation solving with absolute in it

Tags: math, equation

I have an equation which I want to simplify in order to retrieve the solution. But the equation contains absolute in it. How can it be more simplified?

```
d = abs(X²-vs²)/2*a1 + abs(vf²-X²)/2*a2
```

**abs** is the absolute of the value inside the parenthesis

**X** is the unknown and we know **d, vs, a1, vf** and **a2**

So in the end the equation would be X = ....

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic because it's not actually about programming. You should either delete and repost on the Math sister site, or edit the post to have some programming content.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a maths problem, not a programming one

Comment: Be careful with precedence rules.  Is that abs(vf²-X²)/2*a2, or abs(vf²-X²)/(2*a2)?  Units would suggest that it should be the latter: L = (L/T)^2/(L/T^2)

Answer (score 2):

A solution for this would be to solve the 4 following equations:

1. d = (X²-vs²)/2*a1 + (vf²-X²)/2*a2
2. d = (vs²-X²)/2*a1 + (vf²-X²)/2*a2
3. d = (X²-vs²)/2*a1 + (X²-vf²)/2*a2
4. d = (vs²-X²)/2*a1 + (X²-vf²)/2*a2

And then see which solutions are compatible with the initial equation.

Comment: Yeah, I do that and it works fine, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is to rewrite the *one* `abs(A) ... = 0` equation into `2` with *conditions*:

```
 abs(A) ... = 0
```

is equal to

```
  A ...      = 0 when A >= 0
 -A ...      = 0 when A < 0
```

In your case we can turn then initial equation into *three* . Let's suppose that

```
  vs**2 < vf**2
```

so we have **3** cases:

```
  X  <= vs        so abs(X**2 - vs**2) = -(X**2 - vs**2) ; (vf**2 - X**2) = vf**2 - X**2
  vs <  X  <= vf  so abs(X**2 - vs**2) = X**2 - vs**2 ; (vf**2 - X**2) = vf**2 - X**2
  vf <  X         so abs(X**2 - vs**2) = X**2 - vs**2 ; (vf**2 - X**2) = -(vf**2 - X**2)
```

Ans we have three easy to solve equations with conditions on `X`:

```
  d = -(X**2 - vs**2) / 2 / a1 + (vf**2 - X**2)/2 * a2  when X  <= vs
  d =  (X**2 - vs**2) / 2 / a1 + (vf**2 - X**2)/2 * a2  when vs <  X  <= vf
  d =  (X**2 - vs**2) / 2 / a1 - (vf**2 - X**2)/2 * a2  when vf <  X
```

Solve all of them, but take `X` if and only if it met the condition. In case that `vs**2 > vf**2` you have `3` a bit different conditions:

```
  X  <= vf
  vf <  X  <= vs
  vs <  X
```

and equations will be

```
  d = -(X**2 - vs**2) / 2 / a1 + (vf**2 - X**2)/2 * a2  when X  <= vf
  d = -(X**2 - vs**2) / 2 / a1 - (vf**2 - X**2)/2 * a2  when vs <  X  <= vf
  d =  (X**2 - vs**2) / 2 / a1 - (vf**2 - X**2)/2 * a2  when vf <  X
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped me

Answer (score 1):

By definition: 
abs(x) = x if x >= 0,  &
                                          -x if x <=0

So turn this equation into 4 equations, for all combinations of each abs term positive or negative, i.e. + +,   + -,  - +,  - -

Solve each of the four equations, and discard any solutions that don't satisfy the sign assumption about the abs term of that particular equation after you plug the answer back into the abs term. Any solutions remaining that do satisfy the abs sign assumption are the actual answers.